# getting rid of "table.1" from the top of stargazer

Tags: r, r-markdown, stargazer

I'm wondering how to remove the "Table.1" at the top of my stargazer table.

I used right now created a new code chunk in my r document and ran the `stargazer`command.

````
```
{r mylatextable, results = "asis"}
stargazer(lm3a,lm3b,lm3c,lm3d, type = 'latex',header=FALSE)
```
````

I got the following table:

[image]

at the very top we see this "Table.1" text. How do I remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Table.1" text is autogenerated by Latex, from the `\caption{}` tag.  You can remove the `\caption` line using `sub` to suppress this.  Here's an example reproducible Rmd document to demonstrate:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(stargazer)
star = stargazer(attitude, header = F)
star = sub('^.+\\caption.+$','', star)
```

```{r mylatextable, results = "asis", echo=FALSE}
cat(star, sep='\n')
```
````

[image]