# R markdown in Spanish

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I would like to create a report in markdown but in Spanish.

When I create tables with programs such as stargazer, I get 'Table 1' at the top, and the same happens with figures but I need them in Spanish, for example: 'Tabla 1'.

I'd appreciate the help since this is a final investigation project.

[This is the issue example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJWKw.png)

Instead of automatic order in English I want it in Spanish

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Focus on one topic at a time. It's hard to solve all internationalization issues in just one question.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55521433/getting-rid-of-table-1-from-the-top-of-stargazer. But still better would be to include a sample markdown document we can try knitting for testing purposes. It seems to be a latex thing so maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80443/change-the-word-table-in-table-captions could also help.